# matplotlib Error: No module named matplotlib even though it is installed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

No module named matplotlib after installing

I have already installed matplotlib using >> pip3 install matplotlib. As I'm using the latest version of python 3.8.0. 
Even updated the PIP to the latest version

After selecting import matplotlib, it says " No module named matplotlib"

While if I tried to install again received message

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.2.0rc1)"

C:\Users\Username>py
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

C:\Users\Username>pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.2.0rc1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try pip3 install matplotlib so that it installs it on python3 instead of python2

update: not sure If that's how it works on Windows though, it certainly is on Linux.